# mysql query not inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a db query in php that is not inserting into database. Have used this format lots of times but for some reason its not working now. any ideas please

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO `databasename`.`member_users` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `password`, `address1`, `address2`, `postcode`, `access`, `expires`) VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '', '$add1', '$add2', '$postcode', '0', '')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result){
    echo"query inserted";

}else{

    echo "nope";
}
```

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` show?

Comment: As Pekka says, check mysql_error(). Change your `echo "nope";` to `echo mysql_error();`, which will give you the exact reason the query's failing. Just saying 'nope' is useless.

Comment: $postcode = "abc', '0', ''); DROP TABLE  `databasename`.`member_users`; --"

Comment: think i have solved. If the form uses auto insert from previous data (i.e. chrome save details) it does not work. i have no idea why this is

Comment: To clarify @Tyler's comment, the fact that you "Have used this format lots of times" is downright scary.  This is wide open to an attack called "SQL Injection" (google it) and is the MOST insecure way to write database statements.  It is trivial for someone to write a URL that can destroy your database, or harvest its contents unfiltered.  PLEASE read up on SQL Injection and change your ways.

Comment: Thanks, will look into the sql injection! cheers guys!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `echo "nope";` I suggest something like :

```
echo 'error while inserting : ['.mysql_errno().'] '.mysql_error();
echo 'query : '.$query;
```

This way you will be able to see the exact error and the query that was executed.

It can be a lot of things :

1. Constraint error with a foreign key
2. Data type error
3. Non-existent field
4. Wrong database or table name

Comment: think i have solved. If the form uses auto insert from previous data (i.e. chrome save details) it does not work. i have no idea why this is

Answer (score 0):

Instead of...

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `databasename`.`member_users` ..."
```

do

```
$query = "INSERT INTO member_users ..."
```

Hope it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

If databasename and member_users are variables then,
Instead of
 $query = "INSERT INTO `databasename`.`member_users`...
do
 $query = "INSERT INTO `$databasename`.`$member_users`...